# im7 image files to openCV

Tags: python, opencv

Able to show the image through matplotlib, however unable to do it through cv2.imshow. The shape of the image is not consistent with opencv required formats. Require help on changing on changing it so it can be shown by the command cv2.imshow

test.jpg is a random jpg file from web

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ReadIM


img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
vbuff, vatts = ReadIM.extra.get_Buffer_andAttributeList('test.im7')
v_array, vbuff = ReadIM.extra.buffer_as_array(vbuff)

print (np.shape(v_array))
print (v_array[0])
print (np.shape(img))

# Showing image through matplotlib
plt.imshow(v_array[0])
plt.show()

#Showing image through cv2
cv2.imshow('image',v_array[0])
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Remove memory
#del(vbuff)
ReadIM.DestroyBuffer(vbuff)
ReadIM.DestroyAttributeListSafe(vatts)
```

[test.im7](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RCBU2hJCeiCCTYEWmPomb7ranouOFgmF)

Comment: link to `test.jpg` is useless because it ask to login to Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  More importantly, I want to upload test.im7 file. 'test.jpg' file is some random image from google. Any suggestions on how I can upload an file on stackoverflow?

Comment: I changed it to google drive. It should open up for anyone with the link.

Comment: What's an `im7` image please and where do they come from? I've never heard of such a thing.

Comment: im7 files are image files from scientific cameras. They are the format used by LaVISION Gmbh/ Dantec Dynamics and other image based acquisition companies.
https://filext.com/file-extension/IM7

Comment: What is the point of loading a random JPEG from the web and printing its dimensions? Your example should be **Minimum Complete and Verifiable** by StackOverflow rules - it cannot be minimum if it contains extraneous stuff... I am trying to understand and help, not criticise.

Comment: I think it is the wrong Numpy `dtype` to be displayed, try changing to `cv2.imshow('image',v_array[0].astype(np.uint8))`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I will remember that next time. 

I cant change this to uint8, as it will change everything above 255 to 255. I have intensity values ranging from 0 to 3200.

Comment: You could maybe normalise to the range 0..255, using `((i-i.min())/(i.max()-i.min())*255).astype(np.uint8)` where `i` is your array.

Comment: Thanks - I tried this function for normalizing
`img = cv2.normalize(img,None, 255,0,cv2.NORM_MINMAX,dtype = cv2.CV_8UC1)`

Answer (score 1):

Normalizing the image to (0,255) will do the trick

```
img = cv2.normalize(img, None, 255,0,cv2.NORM_MINMAX,dtype = cv2.CV_8UC1)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
```